# ¿como hago para ejecutar una linea de sript en php dentro de una web .html en un servidor remoto?

Tags: php, html, apache

Necesito ejecutar dos lineas de script php dentro de una web .html, son 2 funciones, pero es como que el servidor no las reconoce:

```
                <div class="contact-wrapper">
                <h3>Contactos</h3>
                <p>Haga clic en el boton</p>
                <div class="social-below">
                    <a class="btn button-custom btn-custom-two" <?php =link_contactar_propiedad(85,'Email')?></a>

                    <a class="btn button-custom btn-custom-two" <?php =link_llamar_propiedad(85,'Llamar')?> </a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu archivo tiene extensión .html no reconocerá el codigo PHP a menos que incluyas ese .html en un archivo con extensión .php

Si no estás incluyendo ese .html en otro archivo con extensión .php, el archivo donde llamas a esas funciones debe tener la extensión .php

Comment: Perfecto, he cambiado las extensiones. Gracias